# Best method for determining probability of two independent variables occurring together?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users and traits. like this:

| username1 | trait A |

| username2 | trait B |

| username2 | trait A |

There are several hundred traits. What I am trying to do is to suggest a second trait when a user types in any trait in the table. What I would like to create is a table, using the current data to determine the probability that anyone who has trait A is % likely to also have trait B (or C or D...) So the table would end up being like this:

|trait A | trait B | %probable |

|trait A | trait C | %probable |

For example John likes apples, and we know people who like apples tend to like bananas, so we suggest that john try a banana.

Comment: The probability of two independent events of respective probabilities `m` and `n` occurring together is `m*n,` but somehow I don't think that's what you're asking. What *are* you asking?

Comment: @EJP I edited it to make it more understandable.

Comment: OK now I understand, but what's your question? It seems to me that you don't want a table for this, just a query. Otherwise you have to update the table every time the data it depends on changes, which violates 3NF.

Comment: @EJP I'm just trying to wrap my head around how to go through the existing data, find every person's trait, and determine how often two traits are listed by any individual person. Each time that does (or does not) occur then I know how probably trait A and trait B are to be selected by a given person.

Comment: Say there are one thousand people. Everyone likes pears; one also likes bananas; and another likes all fruit. Can we conclude that because the one person who likes apples also likes both bananas and pears that a likeness for those fruits is *equally probable* for the next apple lover? Or should we adjust for the greater propensity for liking pears overall? Or should we consider that, because 50% of banana lovers and 99.9% of pear lovers do *not* like apples, liking an apple suggests that a fondness for pears is *less likely* than one for bananas--i.e. does `P(A|B)=P(B|A)`? Define your metric!

Comment: Apart from my previous objection, your table is just going to be far too big. If you have several hundred traits, a table keyed on trait pairs is going to have of the order of a million rows. Have a think about how to express the query I suggested in SQL. You need that anyway to construct the table, but I suggest you use the query instead of the table.

Comment: i wonder why this question was downvoted? i thought it was fun.

Comment: @TinTran The close votes so far are all for "unclear what you're asking". You can see that for yourself; no need to wonder about it. You can also see a comment history asking the OP to explain himself, which he has now done, so clearly those votes were justified at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14788c/1/0)

```
SELECT t1.trait,t2.trait as trait2,count(t1.username)
                               /(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) from users)
                               as probability
FROM users t1 JOIN users t2 USING (username)
WHERE t1.trait < t2.trait
GROUP BY t1.trait,t2.trait
```

If you had 400 traits, you'll end up with ([400 choose 2 (79800)](https://www.google.ca/search?q=400+choose+2))rows.

UPDATED: The above is actually **WRONG** because it's dividing by total number of people not accounting for who likes apples.  The correct answer is below ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07f23/3/0))

```
SELECT t1.trait,t2.trait as trait2,count(t1.username)
 /(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT username) from users WHERE trait = t1.trait)
 as probability
FROM users t1 INNER JOIN users t2
  ON t1.username = t2.username
WHERE t1.trait != t2.trait
GROUP BY t1.trait,t2.trait
```

notice the `COUNT(DISTINCT username) from users WHERE trait = t1.trait` and the `t1.trait != t2.trait` instead of the `t1.trait < t2.trait` because it's different depending on which trait we're looking at for example if you have 3 people who likes bananas, 2 of which like cherries: then we can say **100** percent of the people who like cherries like bananas but going the other direction only **66.7** percent of people who like bananas like cherries.

so now if you had 400 traits it's actually 400 x 399 (159600)(twice the previously thought number) possible rows returned.

Comment: My pleasure, well done, +1. If you change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE t1.trait=? AND t2.trait=?`, you get the query I was imagining in comments above, without the `N^2` rows.

Comment: This output is what I'm looking for. Sorry for the initial confusion!

Comment: @SuperNoob, please check my updated answer it's correct now, what you perceived as correct answer before only because in my example I had everyone liking apples, so my example didn't show the incorrectness. Now it's corrected. I only found this bug out when i was doing something similar on my site where i wanted to suggest something like 2 out of 8 people who viewed this definition also viewed some other definition and then i encountered the error as the previous total didn't account for who liked what it was just doing a blind total which is wrong.

Comment: @TinTran Awesome! Thanks for the update. I ran the query and was looking at the results thinking, "something's not right here."